# how to make a function that can only allow specific properties to be updated?

Tags: typescript

I am using a method from a SDK. and for example if I want to update the display name I can use code like this

```
auth.updateUser( "userIdHere", {displayName: "John Doe"} );
```

I want to make something like this:

[image]

as you can see, when I type 'p' there is a drop down list of properties that can be updated. so we can restrict it, only allowing some properties to be updated.

I need to make my own function to be like that. as for now, my function is like this

```
const updateUserData = function(userID: string, updatedData: { [option: string]: any} ) {
    
};
```

I should pass an object as an argument for `updatedData`. but with this approach, I can update all properties I want, there is no restriction

I have tried nymyself

say for example, user is only allowed to update fullname and location. and then I make an interface like this

```
interface UserUpdateRequest {

    fullname?: string
    location?: string
}
```

so the function above will be like this

```
const updateUserData = function(userID: string, updatedData: UserUpdateRequest ) {
    
};
```

but I don't have that drop down list, like this,

( I expect I can find `fullname` on the list )
[image]

am I missing something? what should I do? or at least give me a clue to achieve that :)

Comment: Have you looked at the "keyof" construct? May be what you want.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem.  If I [put your code in the TS Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wEVjZN) then I get the IntelliSense prompt you are looking for (see [this image](https://i.imgur.com/lCKEtsC.png)).  So, uh, possibly this is some issue with your IDE?  Without a [mcve] it's hard to say what's going on.

Comment: @jcalz yup you are right, it is the problem from the IDE.thanks